# How to Add Internal DNS Records in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, coredns

I'm currently setting up a Kubernetes cluster where both private and public services are run. While public services should be accessible via the internet (and FQDNs), private services should not (the idea is to run a VPN inside the cluster where private services should be accessible via *simple* FQDNs).

At the moment, I'm using nginx-ingress and configure Ingress resources where I set the hostname for public resources. external-dns then adds the corresponding DNS records (in Google CloudDNS) - this already works.

The problem I'm facing now: I'm unsure about how I can add DNS records in the same way (i.e. simply specifying a host in `Ingress` definitions and using some ingress-class `private`), yet have these DNS records only be accessible from within the cluster.

I was under the impression that I can add these records to the `Corefile` that CoreDNS is using. However, I fail to figure out how this can be automated.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: If you declare a `Service` for each internal service, you can reach them using the service name. Each service will be added to the DNS when it is created. The name will be visible within the cluster only.

Comment: what are you trying to create? (A record/ CNAME/ etc.)? will this DNS record refer to something inside the cluster or outside the cluster?

Comment: @BurakSerdar of course, but I don’t want users of the VPN to reference applications by their service name but rather by a domain (e.g. instead of gitlab-unicorn, I want to be able to reach the service by typing gitlab.example.com).

Comment: So you have a VPN, and a K8s cluster, and you want the DNS lookups inside the VPN to resolve to services in K8s cluster? I don't know if that's possible at all. Something I would try is to first configure the example.com DNS to respond differently to requests from VPN, but then I'm not exactly sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the problem myself... wrote a little Go application which watches `Ingress` resources and adds `rewrite` rules to the `Corefile` read by CoreDNS accordingly... works like a charm :)

PS: If anyone wants to use the tool, let me know. I'm happy to make it open-source if there is any demand.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar. I would love to see the code you wrote for this purpose. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want them to be accessed publicly, you don't want to add ingress rules for them. Ingress is only to route external traffic into your cluster.

All your services are already registered in CoreDNS and accessible with their local name, no need to add anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes has build-in DNS and each service receives internal fqdn.
These services are not available from the outside unless

- service  type is 'LoadBalancer'
- you define ingress for that service (assuming you have ingress controler like nginx already deployed)

So your sample service deployed in 'default' namespace is accessible inside cluster out of the box via
service1.default.svc.cluster.local

You can change the name by specifying custom ExternalName

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service1
  namespace: prod
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: service1.database.example.com
```

Note that no proxying is done for this to work, you need to make sure given new name is routable from within your cluster (outbound connections are allowed, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an internal DNS server that can resolve the FQDNs, then you can configure the Corefile to forward internal service domain resolution to that DNS server.

For example, if the internal domains/FQDN is `*.mycompany.local`, the Corefile could have a section for that:

```
mycompany.local {
        log
        errors
        ready
        cache 10
        forward . <internal DNS server IP> {
        }

}
```

All the requests to `app.mycompany.local`, or `frontend.middleware.backend.mycompany.local` will be forward to your internal DNS for resolution.

Documentation of `forward` plugin is available here: https://coredns.io/plugins/forward/

Answer (score 0):

As your k8s cluster is hosted with gcloud you can try to use `Cloud DNS`. There you can add a `private zone` with your DNS name.

Then you can push this dns server to your client in your vpn configuration with:

```
 push "dhcp-option DOMAIN gitlab.internal.example.com"
 push "dhcp-option DNS 169.254.169.254"
```

`169.254.169.254` is googles dns, only accessible from inside a google private network